# How to get the POST request entity using Slim framework

Tags: php, android, json, httprequest, slim

I have sent `JSON` data using android java by setting it in the post entity like this:

```
HttpPost httpPostRequest = new HttpPost(URLs.AddRecipe);
StringEntity se = new StringEntity(jsonObject.toString());
httpPostRequest.setEntity(se);
```

How can I receive this `json` data in the `php` , where I am using `Slim framework` ?
I have tried this:

```
$app->post('/recipe/insert/', 'authenticate', function() use ($app) { 
            $response = array();
            $json = $app->request()->post(); 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

JSON is not parsed into `$_POST` superglobal. In `$_POST` you can find form data. JSON you can find in request body instead. Something like following should work.

```
$app->post("/recipe/insert/", "authenticate", function() use ($app) { 
    $json = $app->request->getBody(); 
    var_dump(json_decode($json, true));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the response body. Save it in a variable. After that, verify if the variable is null and then decode your JSON.

```
$app->post("/recipe/insert/", "authenticate", function() use ($app) { 
$entity = $app->request->getBody(); 

if(!$entity)
   $app->stop();

$entity = json_decode($entity, true);

});
```