# Slim 3 getParsedBody() always null and empty

Tags: php, null, slim, slim-3

I'm am using the **Slim Framework Version 3** and have some problems.

```
$app-> post('/', function($request, $response){
  $parsedBody = $request->getParsedBody()['email'];
  var_dump($parsedBody);
});
```

result is always:

> null

Can you help me ?

Comment: Can you explain how your request send data to the app?

Comment: Show an example curl request.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends how you are sending data to the route. This is a POST route, so it will expect the body data to standard form format (`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`) by default.

If you are sending JSON to this route, then you need to set the `Content-type` header to `application/json`. i.e. the curl would look like:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{"email": "a@example.com"}' http://localhost/
```

Also, you should validate that the array key you are looking for is there:

```
$parsedBody = $request->getParsedBody()
$email = $parsedBody['email'] ?? false;
```

Comment: I got NULL with var_dump($request->getParsedBody()); when using either PATCH or PUT request. But POST request returns the request body. Is there a different method for PATCH and PUT?

Comment: @ultrasamad Please create a separate question with a minimal PHP code example and the curl command used to show the problem.

Answer (score 31):

When I switch to slimframework version 4, I had to add :

```
$app->addBodyParsingMiddleware();
```

Otherwise the body was always null (even getBody())

Comment: The question is about Slim version 3, not 4.

Comment: Thank you, my Slim 4 search brought me here.

Comment: Even though this question is about slim 3, you indeed find it always at the top and this  answer is the perfect answer for slim 4 so thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Please, try this way:

```
$app-> post('/yourFunctionName', function() use ($app) {
  $parameters = json_decode($app->request()->getBody(), TRUE);
  $email = $parameters['email'];
  var_dump($email);
});
```

I hope this helps you!

Comment: That will not work for Slim Framework 3, which is what the OP is using.

Comment: Are you sure? It works for me. Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28073480/how-to-access-a-json-request-body-of-a-post-request-in-slim

Comment: That is for Slim Framework version 2, not for Slim Framework version 3. The way the requests work was heavily changed from 2 to 3.

Answer (score 1):

In Slim 3, you must register a Media-Type-Parser middleware for this.

http://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/objects/request.html

```
$app->add(function ($request, $response, $next) {
    // add media parser
    $request->registerMediaTypeParser(
        "text/javascript",
        function ($input) {
            return json_decode($input, true);
        }
    );

    return $next($request, $response);
});
```